# How do I visualize the result of EdgeColoring[g]?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorica

Combinatorica has a heuristic edge-coloring function [`EdgeColoring`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/EdgeColoring.html). When I execute it on a graph, the result is a list of integers. My guess is that an integer $i$ at position $j$ in the list corresponds to coloring the edge $e$ at position $j$ with the color $i$.

The Combinatorica documentation is helplessly scarce, and it's hard for a beginner to understand how to visualize the colored graph. Am I supposed to use `ShowGraph`, or `Highlight`, or something else? For example, consider the following.

```
<< Combinatorica`
g = CompleteGraph[4];
c = EdgeColoring[g];
```

The output is now `{1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1}`. How do I print out the graph with the colors on the edges showing?

Comment: Do you need to use `Combinatorica`? If not [EdgeStyle](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeStyle.html) should be your friend :)

Comment: @Öskå I think I do -- at least for finding the edge-coloring. That is, as far as I know, there is no heuristic nor exact edge-coloring algorithm in Mathematica not depending on Combinatorica. I suppose you could always convert a Combinatorica graph to a built-in graph, but the visualization problem still persists :-)

Comment: Please define what you need to do on a working example. `Combinatorica` is much trickier to use than the rest :)

Comment: @Öskå Thanks for the suggestion, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), you can do the following:

```
CompleteGraph[4, EdgeStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]] // 
 IGEdgeMap[ColorData[68], EdgeStyle -> IGMinimumEdgeColoring]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
<< Combinatorica`
g = CompleteGraph[4];
c = EdgeColoring[g];
colors = ColorData[1, "ColorList"] (* say *);
ShowGraph[g, VertexLabel -> True, EdgeColor -> colors[[c]]]
```

[image]

For graphs in `GraphData[]`, you can use the `"MinimumEdgeColoring"` property:

```
g2 = GraphData[{"Complete", 4}];
c2 = GraphData[{"Complete", 4}, "MinimumEdgeColoring"];
edges = EdgeList[g2];
Graph[Style @@@ Thread[{edges, Thick, colors[[c2]]}], 
       VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]